# Idiomatic way of filtering Failure(t) instances in Scala

Tags: scala, exception, monads, scala-2.11

If I have a `List[Try[A]]` in Scala, what is the idiomatic way to filter out the `Failure(t)` values?

One way is to use the following:

```
val someList: List[Try[String]] = ...
someList.filter(_.isFailure)
```

Is there a more "idiomatic" way, e.g. using `flatten`? This does seem pretty simple.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to get all exceptions you could use `collect` like this:

```
someList.collect{ case Failure(t) => t }
// List[Throwable]
```

If you want to get all success results you could use `flatMap` or `collect`:

```
someList.flatMap{ _.toOption }
// List[String]

someList.collect{ case Success(s) => s }
```